# JavaScript clearTimeout not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a submit function on a textbox with JavaScript. When the script fires, it checks a Kendo grid for a certain article and adds +1 to its quantity as well as opening the corresponding cell in editing mode. What I want to achieve is that on every submit the timer that starts `grid.editCell()` will reset its timer.

Currently, the event fires properly. However, the timer doesn't get reset, although the `clearTimeout()` does work if I just simply start the timer and then clear it right afterwards.

JavaScript:

```
$('#txtBarcode').submit(function (e) {        
    var grid = $("#PickListDetailGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = $("#PickListDetailGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var allData = grid.dataSource.data();
    var code = this.value;
    var notification = $("#notification").data("kendoNotification");
    var timer = null;
    clearTimeout(timer);

    $.each(allData, function (index, item) {
        if (item.ArticleID == code) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
            if (item.Quantity > item.PickedQuantity && item.PickedQuantity.toString().length < 4) {

                var edit = function () {
                    if (item.PickedQuantity != item.Quantity && timer != null) {
                        grid.select("tr:eq(" + (index) + ")");
                        grid.editCell("tr:eq(" + (index + 1) + ") td:eq(" + (5) + ")");  
                    } else {
                        //do nothing
                    }                           
                }   

                item.PickedQuantity++;
                item.dirty = true;
                dataSource.sync();

                if (item.PickedQuantity != item.Quantity) {
                    console.log("tik tok");                        
                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer); //cancel the previous timer.
                        timer = null;
                    }
                    timer = setTimeout(edit, 3000);
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(timer); 
                    timer = null;
                }
                document.getElementById("txtBarcode").value = "";

            } else {    
                if (item.PickedQuantity.toString().length > 4) {

                    notification.hide();
                    notification.show({
                        message: "Added item"
                    }, "upload-success");
                } else {
                    notification.hide();
                    notification.show({
                        title: "Quantity Error",
                        message: "You already picked this item to the maximum"
                    }, "error");
                    document.getElementById("txtBarcode").value = "";
                    grid.select("tr:eq(" + (index) + ")");
                    grid.editCell("tr:eq(" + (index + 1) + ") td:eq(" + (5) + ")");
                    $('.focus :input').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `var timer = null;` had to be outside of the submit function to be properly cleared and set to null before assigning a new `setTimeout()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try delay function like this. The delay function should be outside of the each function.

```
var delay = (function() {
   var timer = 0;
   return function(callback, ms) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
   };
})();

delay(function() {
   //do something
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Why? How does that address the problem?